# HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] not null even Session["UserID"] null after session timeout in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-state, session-timeout

i have set `Session["UserID"]` on page load. like

```
if(!IsPostBack) {
   Session["UserID"] = 1222;
}
```

I am using HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] to verify user session timeout or not.

My web config setting like this,

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
```

After 20 minute `Session["UserID"]` object is null, but at same time, if i verify the `HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]` it show user id.

Please let me know how `HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]` is null after session timeout

Answer (score 0):

The `Session` property of the `System.Web.UI.Page` and `System.Web.UI.UserControl` classes is a reference to `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

You refer to `session["UserId"]` (note lower-case 's') - but you don't say what this is referencing.  Presumably it's defined in your own code, and isn't referencing `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

Comment: I also encountered this problem. **HttpContext.Current.Session** is not null even if **System.Web.HttpSessionStateBase Controller.Session** is null. what is the different between these type of session

Comment: @dush88c - Controller.Session is initialized as part of the initialization for a Controller.  If it's null, the Controller hasn't been initialized properly: perhaps you have created an instance of the Controller yourself.

Comment: No, that is not the case, after session time out , Controller.Session is clear. but HttpContext.Current.Session is not clear.

Comment: @dush88c - I suggest you post a question, preferably with a minimal, complete, verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ok, I got the cause. what happened is Session value is set after time out at the my custom ControllerBase class. Thanks for spend the your time to help me @Joe

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have set session value in custom **controller base** or derived class.

As an example if you check session value for session expired redirection at **ActionFilterAttribute**. please make sure your controller inherited calls have not existed session set methods.

because before calling to controller action method, controller **constructor** will be called.

I believe this will be helpful someone